# Unique value count in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a panda series of long strings.

I want to get the value counts of words in the entire series.  I tried with

```
df.value_counts().to_dict()
```

But it gives the string level count not the word level count.

How can I do it efficiently ?.

My series looks like below

> print df.head(3)
>
> 0     4632 N. Rockwell Street, Chicago Rockwell Neighborhood 773 60625 4748 N Kedzie
>
> 1     4632 N. Rockwell Street, Chicago Rockwell' Bdoy 773 60625 4632 N
>   Rock
>
> 2    4632 N. Rockwell Street, LA Rock hood Grill 773  60625 3658 W
>   Lawren

I wanted to generate a dictionary as follows

```
a['4632'] = 3
a['Rockwell'] = 3
a['LA'] = 1
```

and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is better pure python solution with [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) of joined all values to long string with `split`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter(' '.join(df).split())
#if necessary convert to dict
#d = dict(Counter(' '.join(df).split()))
```

Or use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first:

```
d = df.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().to_dict()
print (d)
{'Rockwell': 4, '4632': 4, 'Street,': 3, '773': 3, '60625': 3, 'N.': 3, 'N': 2, 'Rock': 2, 'Chicago': 2, 'Kedzie': 1, 'Grill': 1, 'Neighborhood': 1, '3658': 1, 'Lawren': 1, 'W': 1, '4748': 1, 'LA': 1, 'hood': 1, "Rockwell'": 1, 'Bdoy': 1}
```